# Format date like system format using Time.getCurrentTimezone()

Tags: android, date, date-format

I'm using `Time.getCurrentTimezone()`to get the current timezone and therefore the date.
I'm getting and formatting it like this:

```
private void setDate() {
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();

    tvdate2.setText(today.monthDay + "-" + today.month + "-" + today.year);
}
```

How can I format the date according to the system settings?
I didn't manage to get it done via SimpleDateFormat...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get time in any format by using SimpleDateFormat class. Please refer to this 
`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String currentDate = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                 Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(currentDate);`

Comment: Thanks but I actually didn't want to use `Calendar`. Any proposal for using my method?